# In Mac, force:org:open: policy denied

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I jus upgraded my Mac and now I cant connect to the org via vscode due to the error.
I set node_tls_reject_unauthorized =0
sfdx_disable_dns_check=true

but no luck.

Error running force:org:open: policy denied

FULL ERROR

1:42:16.180 sfdx force:org:open (node:5062) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification. (Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created) ERROR running force:org:open: policy_denied 11:42:23.667 sfdx force:org:open ended with exit code 1

Comment: what version of MAC OSX? Also what does sfdx --version says?

Comment: Monterey v12.4 and sfdx 7.153.1

Comment: What's your default browser? Also, can you screenshot the full error?

Comment: chrome. i cant upload a picture here. let me rerun it and copy and paster the error

Comment: 11:42:16.180 sfdx force:org:open

(node:5062) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

ERROR running force:org:open: policy_denied

11:42:23.667 sfdx force:org:open

ended with exit code 1

Comment: Are you able to go to the browser and log into Salesforce? The reason I ask is this could be a port block issue. Clearing browser cookies or restart computer does not help?

Comment: yes i can log-in to the org with ease. only in the cli that im having problem